# Are Parijatahara and Amrtaharana forms of Lord Vishnu actually Krishna and Mohini?

Tags: vishnu

I have learned sometimes that Vishnu also has 38 Vibhava forms. The forms called Parijatahara and Amrtaharana are the reasons of this question, because of their names *(Parijata is related to Krishna & Amrtaharana means "the Amrta-took one", which implies Mohini)*.

So my question, are Amirtaharana and Parijatahara same as Krishna and Mohini? If not, how do they look like and what is their story?